# How to apply If-Then statement to the cell dimensions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to adjust row heights to a specific dimension(s) based on the autofit height?

All row heights need to = 12.6 or = a multiple of 12.6. So that wrapped text over 1 line can be set to a height that is multiple of 12.6.

For example, if data on a cell is on 2 lines with wrap text and let' say the autofit height = 23.5. that row would be adjusted to 25.2 (multiple of 12.6).

1 line text = 12.6

2 line text = 25.2

3 line text = 37.8... etc...

I'd imagine an If, then statement would need to be used with < > = but can't quite put it together. I guess these formulas are more commonly used for the value and content of the cells not the dimensions

I tried applying the If Then functions in VBA to apply to the cell/row dimensions and not the actual data in the cells.

Nothing happened

Comment: You say you tried, but it'd be helpful if you share your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

### Adjust Row Height

- I'm not entirely sure but I think only multiples of `0.75` are allowed. Considering this, utilize the following.
- If you try to use `12.6`, the method will convert it to `12.75`, the next multiple of `0.75`.

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:A2")
    
    AdjustRowHeight rg, 12.75

End Sub

Sub AdjustRowHeight(ByVal rg As Range, ByVal RowHeight As Double)
    
    ' Allow only multiples of '0.75'.
    Dim RH100 As Long: RH100 = INT(100 * RowHeight)
    If RH100 Mod 75 > 0 Then RH100 = (Int(RH100 / 75) + 1) * 75
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim H100 As Long
    Dim R100 As Long
   
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        H100 = cell.RowHeight * 100
        R100 = H100 Mod RH100
        If R100 > 0 Then
            cell.RowHeight = (Int(H100 / RH100) + 1) * RH100 / 100
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find an approach that worked!

6 Modify Row Height Based on Condition
https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-vba-row-height/


Sub RowHeightCondition()
    Dim i
    For i = 7 To 1000
        If Rows(i).RowHeight <= 15 Then
        Rows(i).RowHeight = 12.6
        End If
        If Rows(i).RowHeight > 15 And Rows(i).RowHeight < 30 Then
        Rows(i).RowHeight = 25.2
        End If
        If Rows(i).RowHeight > 30 And Rows(i).RowHeight < 45 Then
        Rows(i).RowHeight = 37.8
        End If
    Next i
End Sub